# Mixin, classes and custom elements in Polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer, shadow-dom, css-variables

I create a file called `my-mixins.html` containing:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --red: {
      color: red;
    };
  }

  // This won't work
  .green: {
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

Then I create an element `my-element.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/my-mixins/my-mixins.html">

<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module is="my-element">
  <style>
    .red {
      @apply(--red);
    }
    ...
  </style>

  <p class="red">This is red</p>
  <p class="green">This is not green</p>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element'
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

While `--red` worked (as it's supposed to), `.green` didn't.
I realise this is to make sure that styling doesn't spill etc. But... what's the *actual* rule here? How come `--red` was set and it's available to the module, whereas `green` isn't?

Comment: [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) should help

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my specific question was here:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-style

Specifically:

> Polymer provides a  custom element for defining styles in the main document that can take advantage of several special features of Polymer's styling system:
>
> Document styles defined in a custom-style are shimmed to ensure they do not leak into local DOM when running on browsers without native Shadow DOM.
>
> **Custom properties used by Polymer's shim for cross-scope styling may be defined in an custom-style. Use the :root selector to define custom properties that apply to all custom elements.**

So, the docs explain that the `:root` selector specifically is to be used to set cross-scope custom properties...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it works that way to provide the option to tweak internal styles using CSS custom properties as style placeholders.

Whereas the reason `.green` is not leaking is due to the scoped CSS feature of Shadow DOM.

[You can read more about stylehooks in Eric Bidelman's Shadow DOM v1 primer](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylehooks)